# how to display records from database on each label in asp.net web form?

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, web

i want to display each database value on a seprate lable in table format..

Comment: You need to write code for that... Did you write? Do you know how to retrieve data from one table of the database and display in the UI?

Comment: yup. i know this...

Comment: do u know how to use a gridview?

Comment: yes.. then what..???

Comment: Please show what you had done .there are tones of way to display data

Comment: Also is it Webform or MVC

Answer (score 0):

Considering your question, I have a solution using Repeater control.
Go through below code snippet in which I have displayed Month using repeater.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptCalender">
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    <table style="height: auto; width: 450px; border: 1px solid black">
                        <tr>
                            <td align="center">
                                <span style="font-weight: bold;">Month Name</span>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblMonthName" runat="server" Text='<%#  Eval("MonthName")%>' />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    </table>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And the code behind for the same is below,

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
        BindCalenderData();
}   

void BindCalenderData()
{
    string[] monthList = DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.MonthNames;

    DataTable dtCalenderData = new DataTable();
    dtCalenderData.TableName = "Calender";
    dtCalenderData.Columns.Add("MonthName", typeof(string));

    int totalMonth = monthList.Length;
    for (int counterMonth = 0; counterMonth < totalMonth; counterMonth++)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(monthList[counterMonth]))
        {
            DataRow drRowData = dtCalenderData.NewRow();
            drRowData["MonthName"] = monthList[counterMonth];
            dtCalenderData.Rows.Add(drRowData);
        }
    }

    rptCalender.DataSource = dtCalenderData;
    rptCalender.DataBind();
}
```

I hope this will solve your query.